# Homogenous vector bundles

Tags: mathematical-physics

In the definition of homogenous vector bundles, an equivalence class is defined.

Briefly:

G is a lie group and H a (lie) subgroup. Define

$$
\rho : H \rightarrow GL(V)
$$

where V is a vector space.

The equivalence class is defined as

$$
(g_1, v_1) = (g_1h, \rho(h^{-1})v_1) 
$$

The question is why the above definition and not

$$
(g_1, v_1) = (g_1h, \rho(h)v_1) ?
$$

Answer (score 3):

The first definition
$$
(g, v).h ~:=~ (gh, \rho(h^{-1})v)
$$
defines a right [group action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) $G \times V \times H \to G  \times V$, 
$$
((g, v).h).k~=~(g, v).(h.k),
$$
while the second definition 
$$
(g, v) ~\mapsto~ (gh, \rho(h)v) 
$$
is neither a left nor a right group action, cf. Chris Gerig's comment.

Comment: This completes the picture. The second definition wouldn't work in an obvious way

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Qmechanic's response, here is a a step by step demonstration of why one definition works and the other does not:

$$

(g,v)hk = ((g,v)h)k = ((gh, \rho(h)v)k = ((ghk, \rho(k)\rho(h)v) = ((ghk, \rho(kh)v) \neq (g,v)hk

$$

From the above the second definition does not work.

On the other hand

$$

(g,v)hk = ((g,v)h)k = ((gh, \rho(h^{-1})v)k = ((ghk, \rho(k^{-1})\rho(h^{-1})v) = ((ghk, \rho(k^{-1}h^{-1})v) = 
$$

$$

  ((ghk, \rho((hk)^{-1})v) = (g,v)hk


$$